# Why value is assigned after usage in method?

Tags: java, android-studio, exoplayer

So, I was bothering with this issue.
I have in my code value named
`public String currentSong = "artist- title";`
and I use it in code like this

```
private MetadataOutput getSongTime() {

    return new MetadataOutput() {
        @Override
        public void onMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
            final int length = metadata.length();
            if (length > 0) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(existingURL.split("play")[0] + "currentsong").build();
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                        call.cancel();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                        currentSong = response.body().toString();
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(RadioService.this, currentSong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    };
}
```

But value in Toast is always behind the change (on second run it have value I expected on first run)
Is there any way to make it work correctly?

Comment: Move the call to `Toast.makeText()` to the `onResponse()` callback.

Comment: the problem is that the toast is only there for a check of value, I need to use the value outside of function and through this way may work

Comment: In that case, you'll need to understand how async requests work. You cannot use asynchronously assigned values (from your callback) immediately inside your synchronous code. You delay any execution that requires that value by implementing it or calling other functions from within your `onResponse()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

`currentSong` get the value on the onResponse, and its asynchronous

You must wait the response to show the Toast Message

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws  IOException {
    currentSong = response.body().toString();
    // you new a new Thread to show info in the screen beacausre the methos is asynchronous
    Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // show toast here
        }
    }
}
```